# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.4.1

Tags: android, gradle, windows-10, android-emulator, expo

I faced the problem, more correct in gradle, when I enter the command - npx react-native run-android into the console - it gives me the following error :

**Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Da'.

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.4.1.

Searched in the following locations>
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.4.1/gradle-6.4.1.pom -https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.4.1/gradle-6.4.1.pom

Initially - the problem was incompatibility between gradle and android versions, but after i changed version of gradle and terminal automatically download new version into directory, first error disappeared, but i got another (current problem). I had try some advice before asking question in StackOverFlow, but they didn't work. Here some characteristics :
[React-Native Doctor image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcL8r.png)

Gradle code : [gradle.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2zCy.png) ,
[gradle-wrapper.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoI8x.png)

Gradle Directory : [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcI6K.png)

Path variables  :[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLszN.png)

I appreciate all help (I think, that issue is in PATH, but not sure). By the way - does anyone know, how to add pictures without link?

Comment: Follow @Gabriele Mariotti's answer.
You should also update gradle distributionurl in gradle-wrapper.properties.
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip
Please accept his answer if you fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing gradle with the gradle plugin.

The gradle plugin `6.4.1` **doesn't exist**.

Use the latest stable version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
```

Check also the compatibility with the [gradle version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?gclid=Cj0KCQjwxJqHBhC4ARIsAChq4asvu7acMgRA-tUKvJ263gkgzroSFgjOxRVZFtbvOjeDE3gpuBJ2VpkaAqkXEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#updating-gradle):

```
Plugin version  Required Gradle version
4.0.0+          6.1.1+
4.1.0+          6.5+
4.2.0+          6.7.1+
```

Comment: Could you update this for plugin version 7.1.1 and what plugin would go with gradle-6.8